# Is it possible to make a unique index with id when active= 1?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to ask you it is possible to unique fields when a column is 1 ?

I have a table sales defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sales 
(
    id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    p_id UUID REFERENCES product(id),
    percentage SMALLINT,
    expires timestamp NOT NULL,
    active SMALLINT DEFAULT 1,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

I want to say when `p_id` exists and `active` is 1, then I want to avoid that anyone can insert again this.

When `active` is 0, then it possible to insert product id with `active = 1`

Comment: That is not 100% clear to me. Can you show some sample `INSERT`s and describe which ones should succeed and which ones should fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create an unique index based on the combination if p_id and active you could do something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_of_the_index
ON sales (p_id)
WHERE active = 1;
```

With that index no two rows with the same p_id and active = 1 can be inserted into your sales table.

Check out the doc here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html

Comment: A better reference would be https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html

Answer (score 2):

> I want to say when p_id exists and active is 1 then I want to avoid that anyone can insert again this. When active is 0 then it possible to insert product id with active = 1

Yes, it is possible.

1/ You can create unique indexes. It can also ensure that no two rows in a table can have the same value in the specified column(s)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexname 
ON sales (p_id) 
WHERE active = 1;
```

You can check out the doc here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html

2/ You can create unique constraint. It can ensure that no two rows in a table can have the same value in the specified column(s):

```
ALTER TABLE sales
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_sales_p_id UNIQUE (p_id);
```